# ASP.NET - Best ways of ensuring data isn't lost from FormView?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET application - one part of the system contains quite a lengthy FormView, used for creating or updating jobs on the system. One issue that our customer is concerned about is potential data loss - I.e the user making changes on the form, and forgetting to click 'Save'. We have explained that the web is inherently stateless which makes it difficult, however this remains a big concern.

The obvious 'solution' is posting back every time a value is changed, but even with an UpdatePanel it is very slow and the user loses their focused column. We were also looking at capturing any links and giving the user a prompt to say they haven't saved, but it leaves a lot of variables such as them closing their browser down.

What I've thought is that we could build up a JSON string and use jQuery to use AJAX to post to another page, and either save the changes to the db or persist them in their session til they click Save, and always warn them of unsaved changes.

Does this sound sensible or am I missing anything obvious? There's lots of apps online that save automatically, what methods do they use?

Comment: I think one way would be to split the form on different sections/pages

Answer (score 0):

Usually they store values only on the client side. Check local storage and session storage:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

> The obvious 'solution' is posting back every time a value is changed

Its a great solution as you will be able to get the data saved as soon as the users make a change. Its ideal now a days.

Loosing the focus, might not be the issue here, the issue might be the heavy code on the pages due to which it slows down. Try editing the code and changing it into blocks. So that each block gets executed only when the condition is true. This way you can lessen the code to almost 1/4th of its real version.

> We were also looking at capturing any links and giving the user a prompt to say they haven't saved, but it leaves a lot of variables such as them closing their browser down.

True, but to minimize this, you can try using a simple trick, using `||` operator. Check for anything, if its changed, alert the user and break the execution. Like this:

```
if(value == changed) {
  alert('You have not saved yet!');
  return false;
} else if (sec_value == changed) {
  // go on..
}
```

Which means, you stop the execution of the code if you find an unsaved value, so the browser doesn't look for any more values.

You can use your first idea, of saving the Data in a DB. Because user won't like to stick to the session, he might remove all the cache and cookies or even reinstall a new OS, so that's an issue. You should always keep the data on your side.

If you will always keep warning them they will get sick of your JS alerts. Due to this reason, saving the Data via ajax on your side is the best idea!

Answer (score 0):

Using Sisyphus.js can help you:

Read: 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/05/sisyphus-js-client-side-drafts-and-more/

http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/